# Would a service for automated repurchasing of Bitcoins encourage spending?

Tags: wallet, exchanges, buy-bitcoins, taxes, spending

We launched [Reload](https://reload.bitnik.eu), an online service that binds your bitcoin wallet to your bitcoin exchange account (16 supported so far): whenever you spend bitcoins from your wallet, Reload will use your exchange account to immediately repurchase the same amount of bitcoins. Reload also enables automated reporting and bookkeeping. Do you think such services might encourage Bitcoin spending? Are you repurchasing Bitcoins automatically with some other service already? Do you find this kind of service useful?

Comment: Stack Exchange is not intended for opinion-based "polling" questions (please see the "Help" button at the top of the page). I don't think market research is an appropriate use of this site.

Answer (score 2):

This seems rather odd to me. I try to time my purchases *with* Bitcoins for times when the price is high. And I try to time my purchases *of* Bitcoins for times when the price is low. If I use a service like this, I'll either be buying high or selling low, which is not my personal preference.

Comment: Your thinking is very sensible. For me personally it is important that I can purchase things with Bitcoins anytime, any day, no matter of the current price. Basically I am paying all my utility bills with Bitcoin. But since I do not want to get rid of my stash (possibly I bought some of them for a higher price), I use Reload, which buys them back for me immediately after spending. I use Bitcoins for my every day needs and at the same time I am keeping the same stash of them. But I am super interested in reading more perspectives and ideas on the matter.